# how do i write this operation in racket?

Tags: racket

How would I formulate the following operation in racket?

`(n^2 + 300) (13/n)`?

I got the first part done-

```
(define (f n)
  ( +  ( * n n ) 300))
```

So If I type in `(f 2)` I would get `304`.

But How do I add the second part of this equation `(13/n)`?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to just use direct multiplication, this works:

```
(define (f n)
  (* (+ (* n n) 300) (/ 13 n)))
```

If all you are going to do is square a number, then you could also do:

```
(define (f n)
  (* (+ (sqr n) 300) (/ 13 n)))
```

And finally, if you needed to raise n to some power, then you could also do:

```
(define (f n)
  (* (+ (expt n 2) 300) (/ 13 n)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is straightforward:

```
(define (f n)
  (* (+ (* n n) 300) (/ 13 n)))
```